# PHP app in liferay - HTTP Status 404

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, content-management-system, liferay

I'm a liferay newbie. I'm trying to write a simple php app that echos some text and add it as a plug in to liferay. I've created the file helloworld.php, zipped it up and installed it. Finally I add it to the page but am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /helloworldapp/
type Status report
message /helloworldapp/
description The requested resource (/helloworldapp/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
```

Can anyone help me?

Jonesy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text editor had slying appended a .txt onto the end of index.php

I only saw it when I displayed the directory in the CLI. removed the extension and it works..

Answer (score 0):

You are using Apache **Tomcat** Server right? And the code is a PHP script? I am more confused as what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Liferay is a CMS in Java so it runs on Tomcat and allows you to add PHP apps as portlets